# How to conduct Johanson's cointegration test with variables stationary at I(0)?

Tags: cointegration

How do you interpret the Johanson's cointegration test if you are doing Granger causality and both variables are stationary at I(0)?

Answer (score 1):

If both variables are I(0) then they are not integrated, ie. you say the variables are stationary.  As such you do not need to conduct a cointegration test!  If variables are cointegrated, then there exists a vector that has coefficients that creates a stationary linear combination of the variables.  If the var's are already stationary then this test is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Johansen however allows for $I(0)$ variables, arguing that they are cointegrated with themselves, basically.